# Is getting user configuration input a good reason to start and activity from a service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I see a few existing question about calling startActivity() from a service, and they all recommend not doing that. But what if I have a service that needs configuration info from the user to be used effectively by the main activity? If the main activity sends a message to the service saying, "Hey! The user says he wants to configure you now!", would that be an appropriate reason for the service to start an activity?

Or is there some completely different and more stylisticly correct way to provide user configuration for a service that normally runs entirely in the background?

Comment: Why do main activity not start "configuration" activity? Why do you need do that through service?

Comment: Because the service is an opaque plugin, and the main activity knows nothing about the configuration info it needs, it only knows how to talk to it once it is configured properly.